# Azure pipeline: could not extract archive

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I have an Azure pipeline that is supposed to build a project and copy the jar to Artifactory. Here is the yml that is supposed to install node:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

I can't get it to run.  It fails with

> Could not extract archive:
> '/home/abc-vsts-user/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/10.14.2/node-10.14.2-linux-x64.tar.gz':
> Input is not in the .gz format

I don't understand why it thinks a file in .gz format is not in .gz format!

While your educating me, could you explain what /home/abc-vsts-user is?  Is that an Azure virtual machine?  An Artifactory VM?  The only place (that I know of) where that file is located is in Artifactory.

Any suggestions?

EDIT
Here is the agent:

```
pool:
  name: jvdc-static-pool
  demands:  
  - Agent.Name -equals jvdc-agent-2
```

Comment: can you share what written on your YAML in azure pipeline, the /home/abc-vsts-user could be your working directory runtime variable - $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Comment: I added the YAML to the post.  Is  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)  on an Azure VM, or an Artifactory VM?

Comment: the YAML snippet not specify which type of agent (MS hosted/self-hosted)  you use, in fact you are running this on the agent.

Comment: It seems like a Linux build server - is it an hosted build agent? If yes, set the pool image if you need eg Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yes, it is a hosted build agent.  I've added that part of the yaml to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be due to having an npm install script also in the same pipeline.

```
    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'Npm install, build, and test'
```

That was causing a second attempt at installing node when all that was necessary was

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```